# AWS EC2 deny http/https access to specific IPs via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-security-group

Periodic review of `ssl_access` https logs reveals more than a few pesky vulnerability probers out there.  I wish to specifically block these inbound IPs in a programmatic way, e.g. `aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress` or similar.  There is plenty of material describing how to restrict access to a few known IPs but I cannot seem to find anything that describes permitting all *except* a handful (perhaps a dozen or so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with security groups. Your options are:

- [AWS Network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html)
- [AWS Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/)
- Use something on your EC2 instance like [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: Clear and to the point; thanks.